# How to access to extend user information from the template in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am extended user.model to ClientUser I want to have access to ClientUser information using current user from the template side.
I want to display the name of the company in my template, something like this {{user.company}}

```
class ClientUser(models.Model):
    client = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.company) + '  -  ' + str(self.client)

class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    company_url = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{{ user.clientuser.company.company_name }}
```

Comment: Awesome mate, I was trugguling for hours I made a filter to solve this but your solution is the best thanks...